# Building MSVC6 compatible DLL's with Newer Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2010

I'm about to begin a project for building a plugin to a large simulation system built with MSVC6, and offering instructions for compiling DLL's using MSVC6.

I have MSVC10 and 2012 available, and I'm wondering if it's even possible to configure these to build "down" to MSVC6 compatibility.  Seems last time I dug into this, the answer was a resounding "No".  Do I have to find an old MSVC6 install?

Update: There's also a 64-bit Visual Studio 2008 version of this that I could develop against, so same question: Can I configure a "new" visual studio (like 2012 or so) to compile down to VC6 or 2008 compatibility?

Comment: MSVC6 was infamously buggy and non-standard compliant.  Getting the VS2008 or VS2012 to reproduce the VS6 quirks is a resounding NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an alternative approach, if you create your new project as a COM dll you can interact with it from MSVC6 however you will need to deliver any new linked runtime dlls as well in your resulting setup.